# Woocommerce checkout loading spinner taking 30 seconds to forward to stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I use Woocommerce in a Webshop for a customer. However on the Checkout page, when clicking the place order button the spinning wheel indicating that the page is redirecting is taking about 30 sec to redirect to stripe.

Here is a video of that: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jWydAReXJsghksQ2sJtiK-nFDmkqYMaj

Is there any way to figure out why it is taking so long? A lot of customers are reloading the page after 10-20 seconds as they think it is not working.

**EDIT**: I now figured out that the issus appear to come from `?wc-ajax=complete_order` that take more than 20 second to process. Is there anything I can do to reduce the loading time for this? See the screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NOJwAyupCYEbYXnS6PjRn-QoTLN2EXEq/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out a way to get `?wc-ajax=complete_order` to load faster. Just implement this code into your child-themes functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails', '__return_true' );
```

This will defer the sending of the transactional emails.
This reduced the time from 20 sec to 6 seconds. If you got any more tips how to reduce the loading time below 6 seconds, that would be great!